# How can I listen in real-time for webhooks in asp.net webforms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, post, webhooks

I'm trying to capture the webhooks from the site https://www.unbounce.com in my asp.net web forms application.

I've created HttpAsyncHandler in **WebHookHandler.cs**

```
public class WebHookHandler:IHttpAsyncHandler
{
    public WebHookHandler()
    {
    //
    // TODO: Add constructor logic here
    //
    }
    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
    public IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, object extraData)
    {
        context.Response.Write("<p>Begin IsThreadPoolThread is " + Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread + "</p>\r\n");
        AsynchOperation asynch = new AsynchOperation(cb, context, extraData);
        asynch.StartAsyncWork();
        return asynch;
    }

    public void EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
class AsynchOperation : IAsyncResult
{
    private bool _completed;
    private object _state;
    private AsyncCallback _callback;
    private HttpContext _context;

    bool IAsyncResult.IsCompleted { get { return _completed; } }
    WaitHandle IAsyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle { get { return null; } }
    object IAsyncResult.AsyncState { get { return _state; } }
    bool IAsyncResult.CompletedSynchronously { get { return false; } }

    public AsynchOperation(AsyncCallback callback, HttpContext context, object state)
    {
        _callback = callback;
        _context = context;
        _state = state;
        _completed = false;
    }

    public void StartAsyncWork()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(StartAsyncTask), null);
    }

    private void StartAsyncTask(object workItemState)
    {
        _context.Response.Write("<p>Completion IsThreadPoolThread is " + Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread + "</p>\r\n");
        _context.Response.Write("Hello World from Async Handler!\r\n");
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(_context.Request.InputStream))
        {    
            string postData = reader.ReadToEnd();
            _context.Response.Write(postData);
        }


        _completed = true;
        _callback(this);
    }
}
```

and register my handler and add the map in **web.config**

```
<add verb="*" path="webhook.handler" name="WebHookAsyncHandler" type="WebHookHandler"/>
```

This all is actually taken from msdn (no reputation, sorry)

Next, the other site (unbounce.com) POST something like this:

```
data.json: {"time_submitted":["04:59 PM UTC"],"page_uuid":["3282389-f13a-44b0-9a49-6321b515d43"],"email":["test@test.com"],"page_name":["Test name"],"date_submitted":["2017-07-17"],"name":["tester"],"ip_address":["80.80.80.80"],"page_url":["http://somepage.url"],"variant":["a"]}
```

everytime the user presses the button. The POST url is: example.com/webhook.handler

But I don't get the posted data. The output is:

```
Begin IsThreadPoolThread is True
Completion IsThreadPoolThread is True
Hello World from Async Handler!
```

I tried also use _context.Request and _context.Request.Form before StreamReader, but they was NULL everytime.

I think, I have some global misunderstading of how these things work. Can you please help me to display the data from the POST request to my site on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turned out, that everything was ok in my listing.
You just need to set up a good testing enviroment to catch these POSTs, or better, to do them yourself.